# Java Google chrome decrypt

Tags: java, sql, google-chrome, encryption

I am trying to decrypt chromes encrypted field, but i get the following exception :-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.sun.jna.Structure.getFieldOrder()Ljava/util/List;
at com.sun.jna.Structure.fieldOrder(Structure.java:868)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.getFields(Structure.java:894)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.deriveLayout(Structure.java:1042)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.calculateSize(Structure.java:966)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.calculateSize(Structure.java:933)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.allocateMemory(Structure.java:360)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:184)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:172)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:159)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:151)
at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinCrypt$DATA_BLOB.<init>(WinCrypt.java:42)
at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(Crypt32Util.java:121)
at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(Crypt32Util.java:103)
at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(Crypt32Util.java:90)
at JPasswordManager.ChromeManager.main(ChromeManager.java:8)
```

Here is a snippet from my chrome class (Edit here is a sample code note - password field can be some other encrypted field i just quickly set it to that...):-

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  try
  {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:\\Users\\Standard User\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Login Data");
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT username_value, password_value FROM logins"); // some encrypted field

    while (resultSet.next())
    {
        byte[] encryptedData = resultSet.getBytes(1);
        byte[] decryptedData = Crypt32Util.cryptUnprotectData(encryptedData);  // exception over here

        StringBuilder decryptedString = new StringBuilder();

        for (byte b : decryptedData)
        {
           decryptedString .append((char) b);
        }

        System.out.println("decrypted = [" + decryptedString + "]");
   }
 }

 catch(Exception e)
 {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }

}
```

i have also tried converting to hexString and then decrypting, that too did not work in case if you are intrested in knowing how i had converted to hex then here is a method that i coded

```
public static String ToHexString(byte[] bytes)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb);
    for (byte b : bytes)
    {
        formatter.format("%02x", b);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

i used to pass encryptedData variable through this method and then try to cryptUnprotect the data but still it did not work..

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? see http://www.sscce.org/ And the full stacktrace please.

Comment: @pyb i edited my post

Comment: @GamerJohn are you using 32 bit or 64 bit version of java?

Comment: @NullSaint 64 bit...